# Angular 4 Post not working when connecting to asp.net web service

Tags: asp.net, angular, web-services

I am using Angular 4 as front-end and it's supposed to use ASP.NET web service. angular 4 http.get is getting results just fine, but when applying http.post, it is getting this error,

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: text/plain.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

In chrome developer extensions, I am getting that the request-type is "POST" and content-type is "text/plain; charset=utf-8", so when I am using RequestOptions in angular 4 like the following, the request-type gets changed to "OPTIONS":

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });   
let options = new RequestOptions(
    { 
        headers: headers          
    }
);

var body = JSON.stringify(resource);

return this.http.post(this.url, body, options)
    .map(response => response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

I think, it's not a CORS issue, because when I am using postman, and set the content-type to "application/json" there, everything is fine. But angular creates problem here. Don't know what to do.

Comment: Did you try not to `stringify` the body?

Comment: yes, then the request-type still remains options, even if I omit the options param in the http.post method, "request-type" still remains as options.

Comment: OPTIONS is a separate request.  Chrome (and probably firefox) will send an OPTIONS request before the POST request, to verify that the server will accept the POST request.  IF the OPTIONS request fails (as is probably happening on your request) then the POST never goes out.  First, you'll need to set up the server to accept the OPTIONS request, then once that request passes, Chrome will follow up with the POST request.

Comment: it **is** a CORS issue...

Comment: Ah, did not read the `OPTIONS` part. Then yes, read [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) for more info

Comment: @Jason spradlin, you seem quite spot on, because internet explorer doesn't have this problem. So I guest, for chrome and firefox to work, I have to set up the server to accept OPTIONS request. Thank you very much.